# Spinning javascript menu

Tags: javascript, flash, menu, navigation

I would like to create a spinning menu akin to the one done in flash [here.](http://accuval.net) Are there any relevant links you know about to help with this endeavor?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the <canvas> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a series of images and just swap them. Without getting into complexities of cross-browser canvas/svg that's probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a circular image map with the mouseovers, and then use [css rotates](http://simonjobling.com/blog/2008/rotating-with-css/) with animation on the angle in something like jQuery so that the currently selected item is at the top. However, this would be limited in the amount of browsers that support it (mozilla and webkit). I think there is a similar thing in IE, but requires an ActiveX overlay